# Same table, multiple left joins, with conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql, left-join

Simplifying the problem, I have two tables - item, and item_info.

Item looks like this:

```
+-----+----------+
| id  | title    |
+-----+----------+
|   1 |   lorem1 |
|   2 |   lorem2 |
|   3 |   lorem3 |
|   4 |   lorem4 |
|   5 |   lorem5 |
+-----+----------+
```

item_info looks like this:

```
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+
| id  | item_id  | field_name    | field_value   |
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+
|   1 |        1 | tag           | a_tag1        |
|   2 |        1 | tag           | a_tag2        |
|   3 |        1 | series_title  | bob_show      |
|   4 |        1 | tag           | b_tag1        |
|   5 |        1 | tag           | b_tag2        |
|   6 |        2 | tag           | a_tag3        |
|   7 |        2 | tag           | a_tag4        |
|   8 |        2 | series_title  | jane_show     |
|   9 |        2 | tag           | b_tag3        |
|  10 |        2 | tag           | b_tag4        |
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+
```

I'm trying to get a result that looks like this:

```
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id  | title    | series_title  | a_tags        | b_tags        |
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|   1 |   lorem1 | bob_show      | a_tag1,a_tag2 | b_tag1,b_tag2 |
|   2 |   lorem2 | jane_show     | a_tag3,a_tag4 | b_tag3,b_tag4 |
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I need to limit the resultset to a particlar list of item.id rows. I'm attempting to do this with multiple left joins:

```
select i.id as 'id', i.title as 'title', info.field_value as 'series_title',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT info2.field_value) as 'a_tags', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT info3.field_value) as 'b_tags'
from item i
left join item_info info on i.id = info.item_id
left join item_info info2 on i.id = info2.item_id
left join item_info info3 on i.id = info3.item_id
and i.id in (1,2)
where info.field_name = 'series_title'
or info2.field_name = 'tag'
and info2.field_value like "a_%"
or info3.field_name = 'tag'
and info3.field_value like "b_%"
group by 1;
```

I can't tell if this works because the query is taking forever and my ops people get cranky when we run queries that take forever. Can anyone help me streamline the query and make sure I'm building it the correct way?

Comment: Why `bob_show` has `a_tag1`, `a_tag2` in `a_tags`?

Comment: This query doesn't really work the way it's written. It's running a long time because there is no WHERE clause on the item table; this query is going to retrieve every row from item. The predicate `i.id in (1,2)` does appear in the JOIN predicate for info3; but that is just going to limit the rows returned info3. See my answer for a coouple of example queries that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some of those predicates belong in the ON clause, rather than the WHERE clause, if you don't want to negate the LEFT join, and the predicate on i.id belongs in the WHERE clause (if you want to limit the rows returned, rather than limit the rows joined from info3.

This should return the specified resultset:

```
SELECT i.id AS `id`
     , i.title AS `title`
     , info.field_value AS `series_title`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT info2.field_value ORDER BY info2.field_value) AS `a_tags`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT info3.field_value ORDER BY info3.field_value) AS `b_tags`
  FROM item i
  LEFT
  JOIN item_info info 
    ON info.item_id = i.id
   AND info.field_name = 'series_title'
  LEFT
  JOIN item_info info2
    ON info2.item_id = i.id
   AND info2.field_name = 'tag'
   AND info2.field_value LIKE "a_%"
  LEFT
  JOIN item_info info3 
    ON info3.item_id = i.id
   AND info3.field_name = 'tag'
   AND info3.field_value like "b_%"
 WHERE i.id in (1,2)
 GROUP 
    BY i.id
```

There is a potential for creating a large resultset, with the rows from info2 (effectively) cross joined with the rows from info3.  (20 matching rows from info2 and 20 matching rows from info3, would result in 20*20=400 rows for each row from items.)

If you are returning only one or two rows, then sometimes a correlated subquery will perform better. (This is NOT true for large sets, because of the number of times the subqueries get executed... once for each row.)

```
SELECT i.id AS `id`
     , i.title AS `title`
     , ( SELECT info.field_value
           FROM item_info info
          WHERE info.item_id = i.id
            AND info.field_name = 'series_title'
          ORDER BY info.field_value
          LIMIT 1
       ) AS `series_title`
     , ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT info2.field_value ORDER BY info2.field_value)
           FROM item_info2 info2
          WHERE info2.item_id = i.id
            AND info2.field_name = 'tag'
            AND info2.field_value LIKE "a_%"
          GROUP BY info2.item_id
       )  AS `a_tags`
     , ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT info3.field_value ORDER BY info3.field_value)
           FROM item_info3 info2
          WHERE info3.item_id = i.id
            AND info3.field_name = 'tag'
            AND info3.field_value like "b_%"
          GROUP BY info3.item_id
       )  AS `b_tags`
  FROM item i
 WHERE i.id in (1,2)
 ORDER BY i.id
```

This also eliminates the need for the GROUP BY (if i.id is unique), though you probably want to add the ORDER BY so the result set is returned in the same order (as it would have been with the GROUP BY)

But again, this second approach can be a real light dimmer on large numbers of rows returned from item.

Comment: The first answer works perfectly. I am running this for ~500 item rows, so the second would likely be too intensive. Thanks!

Comment: @semi_pro: just to clarify: the performance of that second option is dependent on the number of rows returned from item (i.e. rows NOT filtered out by the WHERE clause.) Those subqueries only get run for rows that get returned, not all rows in the table.  Returning 500 rows would be effectively 500 executions of each of those subqueries, so 1501 queries, albeit, more efficiently than separate queries from a client (from a client, that would have the overhead of 1500 roundtrips to the database (open, parse sql, execute sql, retrieve resultset, close)

Answer (score 1):

Even though your need is satisfied by means of complex queries, I think you have to `redesign` your schema.

Some thing like this.,

```
ITEM
---------------------------
 Item_Id (P) |   Title     | series_title (Nullable)
 1              lorem1       bob_show
 2              lorem2       jane_show
 3              lorem3       NULL
 4              lorem4       NULL 
 5              lorem5       NULL  

TAG
------------------
 Tag_id (P) |  Tag_name | item_id (Ref)  | TAG_GroupID (Ref)
   1            a_tag1        1               1
   2            a_tag2        1               1
   3            a_tag3        2               1
   4            a_tag4        2               1
   5            b_tag1        1               2
   6            b_tag2        1               2
   7            b_tag3        2               2
   8            b_tag4        2               2


Tag_Group
-----------------
Tag_GroupID(Primary)| Tag_GroupName
   1                       a_tag
   2                       b_tag
```

Also, then your query will become,

```
select ITEM.ID, ITEM.TITLE, ITEM.SERIES_TITLE ,
(
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Tag_Name) from Tag where ITEM.ID = Tag.Item_ID AND  Tag.Tag_Group_Id = 1
) as 'A_TAGS'
,
(
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Tag_Name) from Tag where ITEM.ID = Tag.Item_ID AND  Tag.Tag_Group_Id = 2
) as 'B_TAGS'

from ITEM
```

A Practical running approach here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45eba/12/0

Now this one is only static, You could do this in a more dynamic way using `Dynamic Sql`... Which I post in the same answer, when possible soon....

**Dont forget to give me your comments, or what you think about this approch of new schema.**

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately a new schema isn't feasible. The example data I provided is a small subset of a much larger item collection. Also, the series_title tag makes more sense where it is because it only applies to this small item subset. It would be `null` for the overwhelming majority of rows in the item table. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: @semi_pro What's wrong in having null for overwhelming majority of rows, when it schematically make sense. Consider, only very few countries like North korea has dictatorship. so in a country table a field like `HasDictatorshipRule` is more applicable, rather than, having like `CountryID | RuleValue`. Also, I could see your `field value` is more generic in term, but i think if a column has must be `only specific type`.

Comment: @spencer7593 whether my above comment is suitable to this scenario. could you clear to me please.....

Comment: it's a rather moot point, as the architecture of the database is outside of my control. But I see it being a less sensible solution because other item rows likely have similar data that _could_ be set in their own column, but satisfying all of those in the `item` table would create an unruly number of columns. It makes more sense to have the `item_info` table where _any_ non-standard item-related data can be stored.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want.

```
select 
  i.id as 'id', 
  i.title as 'title', 
  series.field_value as 'series_title',
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.field_value) as 'a_tags', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.field_value) as 'b_tags'
from item i
  inner join item_info series on i.id = series.item_id
  inner join item_info a on i.id = a.item_id
  inner join item_info b on i.id = b.item_id
where
  i.id in (1, 2)
  and series.field_name = 'series_title'
  and a.field_value like "a\_%"
  and a.field_name = 'tag'
  and b.field_value like "b\_%"
  and b.field_name = 'tag'
group by 1
```

[Here's the SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ab13/7).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, it was including the "bob_show" field_name in the b tags due to the underscore matching any character. Edited so that these are escaped.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't actually return the full resultset, perhaps because some of the item don't have an a_tag or a b_tag. I didn't specify that in the question though, so your answer works for the way I asked it.